# Name for graph of bit flips

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a technical term for a graph in which the nodes are byte values 0–255 and the edges are flips of one bit at a time? In other words, two nodes are connected if and only if the associated numbers differ in only one bit. Preferably more generally for any size of “byte”, not just 8.

Comment: I think that is called n-cube.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) $Q_8$ (or $Q_n$ for "bytes" of length $n$). It's a special case of a [Hamming graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_graph), since it is the graph corresponding to the Hamming distance between words (but "Hamming graph" is used for more general alphabets, not just binary).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.